# AngularJS Directive using Compile cannot access child elements

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

My intent was to create a directive that could rearrange (not reorder) its child elements into a Bootstrap CSS Grid, but I am having a lot of difficulty getting access to the child elements.

I've tried a lot of different things and have researched Compile vs Link vs Controller directive options. I think I might have to change the 'compile' to 'link' in my directive to get this to work, but I am unsure how to do that.

I have an [AngularJS directive on GitHub](https://github.com/harryhobbes/angular-dyno-grid/) that takes an array or object of parameters to render a simple or complex grid.

In the example below you can see the `layoutOptions.data = [3, 4]` which means the grid will have 3 cells in the top row and 4 in the second. This is working well.

The second step is that I would like to render some divs as child elements of the directive and the directive will place these in the cells of the grid as it is created. This is shown by the `layoutOptions.content = ['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'banana', 'lime', 'lemon', 'grape']` but this needs to be de-coupled so that it could be literally anything.

### HTML Input

```
<div ng-app="blerg">
  <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
    <div class="container" hr-layout="layoutOptions">
      <div ng-transclude ng-repeat="fruit in layoutOptions.content">{{fruit}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Desired (not actual) Output

Actual output is as below, but does not include the inner DIVs with fruit names

```
<div class="container hr-layout" hr-layout="layoutOptions">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"><!-- from ng-repeat --><div>apple</div></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><!-- from ng-repeat --><div>orange</div></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><!-- from ng-repeat --><div>pear</div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"><!-- from ng-repeat --><div>banana</div></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"><!-- from ng-repeat --><div>lime</div></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"><!-- from ng-repeat --><div>lemon</div></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"><!-- from ng-repeat --><div>grape</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And a jsFiddle that uses it here: http://jsfiddle.net/harryhobbes/jJDZv/show/

### Code

```
angular.module('blerg', [])
  .controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.layoutOptions = {
      data: [3, 4],
      content: ['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'banana', 'lime', 'lemon', 'grape']
    };
  })
  .directive("hrLayout", [
    "$compile", "$q", "$parse", "$http", function ($compile, $q, $parse, $http) {
      return {
        restrict: "A",
        transclude: true,
        compile: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          //var content = element.children();
          return function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var contentCount = 0;
            var renderTemplate = function(value, content) {
              if (typeof content === 'undefined' || content.length <= contentCount)
                var cellContent = 'Test content(col-'+value+')';
              else if (Object.prototype.toString.call(content) === '[object Array]')
                var cellContent = content[contentCount];
              else
                var cellContent = content;

              contentCount++;
              return '<div class="col-md-'+value+'">'+cellContent+'</div>';
            };

            var renderLayout = function(values, content) {
              var renderedHTML = '';
              var rowCnt = 0;
              var subWidth = 0;

              angular.forEach(values, function(value) {
                renderedHTML += '<div class="row">';
                if(Object.prototype.toString.call(value) === '[object Array]') {
                  angular.forEach(value, function(subvalue) {
                    if(typeof subvalue === 'object') {
                      renderedHTML += renderTemplate(
                        subvalue.w.substring(4), renderLayout(subvalue.d)
                      );
                    } else {
                      renderedHTML += renderTemplate(subvalue.substring(4));
                    }
                  });
                } else {
                  if(value > 12) {
                    value = 12;
                  } else if (value <= 0) {
                    value = 1;
                  }
                  subWidth = Math.floor(12 / value);
                  for (var i=0; i< value-1; i++) {
                    renderedHTML += renderTemplate(subWidth);
                  }
                  renderedHTML += renderTemplate((12-subWidth*(value-1)));
                }
                renderedHTML += '</div>';
                rowCnt++;
              });
              return renderedHTML;
            };

            scope.$watch(attrs.hrLayout, function(value) {
              element.html(renderLayout(value.data));
            });
            element.addClass("hr-layout");
          };
        }
    };
  }]);
```

Comment: From your code I could just understand that you're rendering a DIV based grid and on resize event the divs get reordered using CSS. I did not understand what exactly are you expecting? Can you put more information on this?

Comment: @codef0rmer I've updated the question. I did not think I was using a resize event. Is this the scope.$watch statement?

Comment: Is that the expected output? The only difference is that column value is dummy than the actual fruit.

Comment: @codef0rmer Yes that is the expected output. Somehow I need to allow the ng-repeat to complete before accessing the child elements in the hrLayout directive. Once I access them I can start processing the grid and moving the child divs to their final location.

Comment: I think you better pass `content` along with `layoutOptions` in hr-layout and then make up your `div` structure within compile method as you'll have access to both content and layoutOptions.

Comment: The directive should be abstracted enough to not know what the child elements are. This way the child elements could be a mixture of tables, images, graphs, even another directive and all the directive needs to do is move them into place in the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help - http://jsfiddle.net/PwNZ5/1/

```
App.directive('hrLayout', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        // allows transclusion
        transclude: true,

        // transcludes the content of an element on which hr-layout was placed
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',

        compile: function(tElement, tAttrs, transcludeFn) {
            return function (scope, el, tAttrs) {
                var data = scope.$eval(tAttrs.hrLayout),
                    dom = '';

                transcludeFn(scope, function cloneConnectFn(cElement) {
                    // hide the transcluded content
                    tElement.children('div[ng-transclude]').hide();

                    // http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/‎
                    window.setTimeout(function() {
                        for(var row = 0; row < data.data.length; row++) {
                            dom+= '<div class="row">';
                            for(var col = 0; col < data.data[row]; col++) {
                                dom+= '<div class="col-md-' + data.data[row] + '">' + tElement.children('div[ng-transclude]').children(':eq(' + ( row + col ) + ')').html() + '</div>';
                            }
                            dom+= '</div>';
                        }

                        tElement.after(dom);
                    }, 0);
                });
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach looks like too complex. Maybe you should use **ngRepeat** directive http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat and **orderBy** filter http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:orderBy insted of updating html of **element** every time when **hrLayout** was updated?

Comment: I don't think you actually looked at what I am trying to do. I want to render a [Bootstap CSS Grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), not an ordered list. The grid can be nested and very complex, hence the need for this level of complexity. I admit it probably could be done differently and I am happy to hear of possible solutions, but I think you missed the point.

Comment: In your code i still see some hidden logic. It's confusing. Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/jJDZv/7/show/ Is it what you want to do. If not, describe more common case what your program should do. What kind of data you can get to the input of your program (layoutOptions)

Comment: Sloot, thanks for the response. My jsFiddle was a bit confusing and you are on the right track. I had done what you did, but I need the child elements to be uncoupled from the hrLayout. I have change the fiddle to better represent the issue and highlight that the array of fruit could be any complex element including another directive: http://jsfiddle.net/harryhobbes/jJDZv/9/

Comment: Bazmo, as I understand you want to get access to cell DomElement (`<div class="col-md-3">Test content(col-3)</div>`) from DemoCtrl ? Do you need HTML or Object of this element ?  Describe more widely what you need to do, please.

Comment: I want to get access to the directive element's children and move them around the DOM. Think of it as a primary DIV, with N number of children and that primary DIV wants to move them from a list into a grid pattern. The child elements could be anything, therefore the directive can only be aware of them as a list of children to be moved.

Comment: I think I understand your problem. Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jJDZv/26/ . I create another directive which paste  content to the grid.